# how to loop over hostvars of register output

Tags: loops, ansible, ansible-2.x, hostvars

I'm struggling to loop over hostvars of the registered output of all the hosts in dynamic inventory.
Here is the code.

```
$cat collect.yaml 
---
- hosts: "{{ env }}"
  become: True
  tasks:
   - name: Get dockerinfo
     docker_host_info:
       containers: yes
     register: result

- name: Debug dockerInfo
  debug:
    var: result.containers

- name: dynamic grouping
  add_host:
    name: "{{ item[0] }}"  
    groups: "{{ item[1].Image | regex_replace('.*?/(.*?):.*', '\\1') }}"
  loops: 
    -  "{{ ansible_play_batch }}"
    -  "{{ hostvars[item].result.containers }}"
```

Error i get is item not defined. I would want the hosts refer to their respective result.containers. Not sure on how to use hostvars for the host to refer their respective result.containers.

Here is result.container output.

```
TASK [Debug dockerInfo]
ok: [vm1.nodekite.com] => {
"result.containers": [
{
"Image": "ca.docker/webproxy:1.0.0",
},
{
"Image": "docker.local/egacustomer:1.0.1",
},
]}
 ok: [vm2.nodekite.com ] => {
 "result.containers": [
 {
"Image": "ca.docker/webproxyui:1.0.0",
 },
 {
"Image": "cna-docker-local/lega-customer:1.0.1",
},
]}
```

Here is the what i'm trying to achieve

```
changed: [vm1.nodekite.com] => {
"add_host": {
"groups": [
    "webproxy"
],
"host_name": "vm1.nodekite.com",
},
changed: [vm1.nodekite.com] => {
"add_host": {
"groups": [
    "egacustomer"
],
"host_name": "vm1.nodekite.com",
},
changed: [vm2.nodekite.com] => {
"add_host": {
"groups": [
    "webproxy"            >> this should be webproxyui
],
"host_name": "vm2.nodekite.com",
},
changed: [vm2.nodekite.com] => {
"add_host": {
"groups": [
    "egacustomer"           >> this should be lega-customer
],
"host_name": "vm2.nodekite.com",
 },
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I would run this task using Images Names

```
- hosts: "{{ group }}"
  gather_facts: false
  become: true
  become_method: sudo
  tasks:
    - name: stop or restart docker containers
      command: "docker {{ state }} {{ container_name }}"
```

Comment: Can you explain a little about why the image prefixes are going into the host inventory? Is it because you will eventually run some tasks on containers using their image names?

Comment: that's right,Andy. If i select group "webproxy" it should restart/stop the container on vm1.nodekite.com and webproxyui for vm2.nodekite.com.

Answer (score 1):

How about just `group_by` paired with the `loop`?

```
- hosts: "{{ env }}"
  become: True
  tasks:
    - name: Get dockerinfo
     docker_host_info:
       containers: yes
     register: result

    - debug:
        var: result.containers

    - group_by:
        key: "container_{{ item.image | regex_replace('.*?/(.*?):.*', '\\1') }}"
      loop: "{{ result.containers }}"

    - debug:
        var: group_names
```

You don't need to add the prefix. But this would add each host to groups with their container image prefixes. You should be able to use the group later in the play or playbook.

Comment: that's doesn't work! :( it throws me below error:
"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'image'
When i tried this `key: "{{ item.image | regex_replace('.*?/(.*?):.*', '\\1') }}"` with exact code.

Comment: Sorry, I was testing with my own vars. In your case it would be with a capital I: `Image`.